# SQL syntax error adding data opencart DB

Tags: mysql, sql

Im looking to add all products that dont have `attribute_id = 12` into `oc_product_attribute`,

But getting a syntax error...

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12) select ocp.product_id from oc_product ocp where ocp.product_id not in (SE' at line 1

```
insert into `oc_product_attribute` (ocp.product_id, 12)  
select ocp.product_id from oc_product ocp where ocp.product_id not in (SELECT oca.`product_id`
FROM `oc_product_attribute` oca where oca.attribute_id = 12)
```

Am I missing something here, quite new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you have to enumerate columns in `insert` statements.

```
insert into `oc_product_attribute` (ocp.product_id, 12)
```

must be

```
insert into `oc_product_attribute` (ocp.product_id, some_column_name)
```

and I guess it may be `attribute_id`.

For more details, please see the reference manual -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html